# Enable/Disable Delayed Expansion in FOR /f loop (batch)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-line, delayedvariableexpansion

I am still struggling to properly understand the behaviour of Disable/EnableDelayedExpansion...

I want to parse input arguments when calling something like `command -a -b -c file` such to finally have `options=-a -b -c` and `filename=file`.

To do so I use the FOR /f loop:

```
set "count=0"
set "opts="
set "fl="
set tmpv=

:argloop
for /f tokens^=1^,^*^ delims^= %%a in ("%1") do (

    echo.
    echo Chosen option is %1
    set /a count+=1
    echo.
    echo Reading %count% is %%a..

    set "tmpv=%%a"
    rem setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo Tmp is %tmpv% after set equal %%variable.
    rem endlocal
    rem setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    set "tmpv=%tmpv:-=%"
    rem setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo After removing it writes !tmpv!
    rem endlocal
    rem setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    if "%tmpv%"=="%%a" (
        echo Input does not contain "-"
        set "fl=%tmpv%"
        echo %fl%

    ) else (

        echo/Options before are %opts%
        echo.
        if "%opts%"=="" (
            echo Options are empty.
            set opts=%%a
        ) else (
            set "opts=%opts% %%a"
        )
    )
    if not "%2"=="" (shift & goto:argloop)
)

echo.
echo Finally options are %opts%
set opts=%opts:-=/%
echo Finally options are %opts%
echo File name %fl%
set tmpv=
set count=
goto:end
```

Output writes:

```
Chosen option is -a

Reading 1 is -a..
Tmp is  after set equal %variable.
After removing it writes
Options before are

Options are empty.

Chosen option is -b

Reading 2 is -b..
Tmp is -= after set equal %variable.
After removing it writes -=
Options before are -a


Chosen option is -c

Reading 3 is -c..
Tmp is = after set equal %variable.
After removing it writes =
Options before are -a -b


Chosen option is flfl

Reading 4 is flfl..
Tmp is = after set equal %variable.
After removing it writes =
Options before are -a -b -c


Finally options are -a -b -c flfl
Finally options are /a /b /c flfl
File name
```

I had made it working with EnableDelayedExpansion, but not capable of storing final %fl% variable.

But why does it not work this way (without using delayed expansions)??

I will sincerely appreciate whom will try to clarify it in all extents.

Answer (score 0):

The rules really aren't too hard.

You are aware that `%var%` is resolved to the value of `var`.

When a loop is parsed, every `%var%` within that loop is replaced by the THEN-current value of `var`. This includes pseudovariables like %cd%, %errorlevel% and %random%.

If `delayedexpansion` is in effect (and it is "in effect" from the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` instruction [start-of-setlocal-bracket] until an `endlocal` or `end-of-file` [end-of-setlocal-bracket] is reached) then `!var!` is resolved to the contents of `var` at the time that particular instruction (`set`, `echo`, etc) is executed.

If `delayedexpansion` is NOT in effect then `!var!` is simply that - the literal string `!var!`.

And one small kink. Any change made to the environment (addition, deletion or variation of variable values) is discarded when a `setlocal` bracket ends.

So, in all probability, you could display the difference by `echo`ing `%var%` alongside `!var!`

- and `%%x` (a `metavariable`) is always resolved to its *current* value, regardless of `setlocal` status.

[After responses]

Since all `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion/endlocal` brackets are `rem`med-out in the published code, I'm not surprised at the results.

However, running the published code does not yield the published results - for me, the response was "Reading 0"..."Reading 3".

So, looking at the `for` loop, I believe it's equivalent to

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%a in ("%1") do (
```

which in turn is the same as

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%1") do (
```

since there are no delimiters, an this is effectively the same as

```
for %%a in (%1) do (
```

which does nothing beyond assigning `%1` to `%%a` and making the entire loop one `block statement.`

So therefore, this code should do the same job - without the kinkiness afforded by `setlocal`...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "count=0"
set "opts="
set "fl="
set "tmpv="

:argloopn
SET "arg=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED arg GOTO report
SET /a count+=1
ECHO arg %count% is %1 IN variable ARG = "%arg%"
SET "tmpv=%arg%"
rem remove "-"
set "tmpv=%tmpv:-=%"
IF "%tmpv%"=="%arg%" (
    echo Input does not contain "-"
    set "fl=%tmpv%"
) ELSE (
    ECHO Input contains "-" so is option
    SET "opts=%opts% %arg%"
)
SHIFT
GOTO argloopn

:report

rem fix-up options since 1st char, if it exists must be a space as [space]newoption is added each time
IF DEFINED options SET "options=%options:~1%"
echo Finally options are %opts%
set opts=%opts:-=/%
echo Finally options are %opts%
echo File name %fl%


echo.
GOTO :EOF
```

I've assumed that a proper batch-debug environment has been established; hence `goto :eof` to terminate the batch and an inintial `setlocal` to preserve the original environment.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.

--- BUT ---

In testing, I tried this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:parasite
setlocal
set "opts="
:loopp
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%1") DO (
 SET "opts=%opts% %%a"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OPTS was "%opts%" is now "!opts!"
 ENDLOCAL
 ECHO %%opts%% is "%opts%" and !opts! is "!opts!"
)
SHIFT
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :EOF 
GOTO loopp
```

Which didn't do what I expected it to do - that is, report

```
 %opts% is " -a -b -c file" and !opts! is "!opts!"
```

Instead, it reported

```
 %opts% is " -a -b -c file" and  -a -b -c file is " -a -b -c file"
```

Which I find puzzling as the `!var!` is outside the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion/endlocal` command-bracket and hence should *not* have been replaced, in my view.

Seems like an @jeb problem to me... so I'll see whether he's got an explanation...

Comment: I see, but precisely because it should not be so hard, I really don't understand what's going wrong in there. Both %tmpv% and !tmpv! are not behaving as supposed.. you see it? I refer to lines `echo Tmp is %tmpv% after set equal %%variable` and `echo After removing it writes !tmpv!`. In this latter it is evident how !tmpv! is not read literally..
Lastly, since I am not using any `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` everything should be handled with `%tmpv%`, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is, you are changing variables within a code block (your `for` loop), so you need delayed expansion to use those changed variables. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) (several times, if needed; it's the key to understand your problem)

Comment: @jeb : Care to comment on my last observation here? Too much yuletide tucker, perhaps?